# How to show page title and favicon when using a iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, favicon, page-title

**The breakdown:**

I'm using 2 different domains, one is showing via iframe on the other domain.

**Issue:**

When the iframe is activated, the page title in the tab is showing the parent URL, not the title and a blank favicon, I want it to show the parent's page title in the tab and the parent's favicon as I understand when they are 2 different domains it's not possible to use the child's page title and favicon which is fine.

**Question:**

How can I get the parent title and favicon to show on the tab? It shows when the iframe is off, but as soon as it's on and the site is loaded the favi goes blank and the page title becomes the parent URL.

**Side Note:**

My child site is HTML and my parent site is PHP, I'm not sure if that's relevant.

After my tests I have ran it on Chrome and Edge with the same results of failure.

The page title and favicon appear fine on the PHP/Parent site when the iframe isn't on, soon as its on its blank! (when accessing the child site direct without iframe the favi and title are also fine)

Comment: I think this is intentional as a security measure, so when you're entering data into the iframe you can't be fooled into thinking you're entering it into the parent site.

Comment: Can you include the code you tried?

Comment: Hmm, I've seen sites using iframe's and have a favicon, as for the page title i cant say for definite - for the second comment (max) the code i have tried was for domains which are the same, so they wouldn't have worked for my case, for the parent favicon i tried adding the echo line for the favicon as it's PHP - 'cho <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon6.ico" type="image/x-icon" />'

Comment: i have just tried these 2 scripts for the favicon and the page title with no success - <script>
        // Create a link element for the favicon
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel = 'icon';
        link.type = 'image/x-icon';
        link.href = 'path-to-your-favicon.ico';
        
        // Append the link element to the head of the document
        document.head.appendChild(link);
    </script> <script>
        // Set the title using JavaScript
        document.title = "Your Parent Page Title";
    </script>